# Original querystring persists when multiple SSI files are called on a page

Tags: php, apache, ssi

We have a page that includes multiple SSI statements. For example:

```
<body>
Some text<br/>
<!--#include virtual="/path/file.php?f=foo&b=bar" -->
More text<br/>
<!--#include virtual="path/newfile.php?t=test&qs=querystring" -->
</body>
```

The PHP files do some processing based on the querystring values and outputs the HTML.

The first include works fine. Using $_GET, I can retrieve the f and b values without any issues. The problem comes with the remaining include files. When newfile.php is called, for example, and I try to retrieve the t and qs values, they are empty. However, I can retrieve f and b. It seems as if the original querystring persists even when a new querystring is passed to the other include files.

I've tried it locally using WAMP and I have no problems. Therefore, it seems as if it's an Apache or PHP configuration problem on the server. Our sys admin has looked at the configurations and log files and said everything appears fine.

Any ideas on what is happening? Why won't the new querystring values overwrite the original querystring that is passed to the first include file? I've looked everywhere for an answer and have come up completely empty handed.

Thanks in advance!